# API Endpoint password in plain text in hybrid app

Tags: ios, .htaccess, api, ionic-framework, password-protection

I am developing an hybrid app with Ionic (AngularJS) for a client. The app is quite simple and it pulls data from our API Endpoint. The API endpoint itself is not protected yet (nor through .htaccess or anything else).

However I need to include some authentication for it. First I thought that oAuth would be the way to go, however I recon that either or that I have to include a password in plain text in my app, so basically it can be hacked quite easy, even it gets "compiled" for IOS or anything else. Am I wrong or am I am misleading?

Comment: take a look at JWT, it may be what you need.

Comment: Hi Nikola, ok thanks. This looks good.